# C array traversal cause loop on c90 standard (but not on c99)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    double arr[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<=4; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        arr[i] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with gcc(c90) gives an infinite loop(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4...) while compiling with gcc(c99) produces only (0, 1, 2, 3, 4). What can be attributed to the difference?

Comment: With what flags did you compile it? This shouldn't give a infinite loop.

Comment: the array is size 4 and you are setting 5 values `for (i=0; i<=4; i++)` so your are setting something out of bounds which is causing this unexpected thing

Comment: @AyonNahiyan yea i understood that but why does that cause an infinite loop in an older version of a compiler?

Comment: @sri.vatsa This is not related to version of compiler. When you set something out of bound whatever happens next is quite undefined. If you dont see anything unexpected you were just lucky.

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering if there is any way to anticipate the output and  it that depends on the version of compiler. Thanks Anyways :)

Comment: undefined behavior means nothing can be guaranteed. Each compiler version, compiler options can produce vastly different results

Comment: @sri.vatsa I posted the exact reason it is looping infinitely. When you have problems like this, looking at the assembly is often the way to find out why something weird is happening.

Comment: In C, the standard idiom for iterating over an array with N elements in it is `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { …array[i]… }`.  While `<=` is not always wrong, it often is wrong.

Comment: The older version of the compiler apparently didn't place `i` in a register, so the out-of-bounds access to `arr[4]` was resetting `i` to 0, effectively restarting the loop. Newer version of the compiler register-allocated `i` even without explicit optimization flags, making the loop variable unharmed by the out-of-bounds write. As others explained, accessing an array out of its bounds is undefined behavior, and there is no guarantee that the newer compiler would keep producing working code if anything were changed.

Answer (score 6):

You are writing to an element outside the array (namely when `i` is 4).

This leads to undefined behavior hence anything could happen.

Answer (score 2):

`Arr` is declared with *4* values, but you are accessing *5* of it (`i=0; i<=4`). Accessing an array out-of-bounds results in undefined behavior.

What exactly happens if you do that depends on implementation details of the compiler, linker, and OS - if the compiler has put `i` there, you are overwriting i with 0; if it has put your stack frame there, you will end up with a crash, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In loop you are assigning `arr[4] = 0`, but array has only 4 elements (arr[0..3]), so you are assigning value to memory outside of array. In this place compiler has placed `int i`, because it is declared just after array.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the assembly, you'll see that the variable i is stored at the end of the array, right after arr[3]. On my computer, it is not aligned in a way that it is exactly at arr[4] but I'm guessing on yours, the variable i is located exactly at arr[4] and thus you are overwriting it to 0 by going out of bounds in your for loop with the <= instead of <. This means in the last iteration of your for loop, you are setting i to 0 which keeps the loop going infinitely.

```
000000000040052d <main>:
  40052d:   55                      push   %rbp
  40052e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400531:   48 83 ec 30             sub    $0x30,%rsp
  400535:   48 b8 9a 99 99 99 99    movabs $0x3ff199999999999a,%rax       
  40053c:   99 f1 3f 
  40053f:   48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)               # move 1.1 into arr[0] at memory address rbp - 0x20
  400543:   48 b8 9a 99 99 99 99    movabs $0x400199999999999a,%rax       
  40054a:   99 01 40 
  40054d:   48 89 45 e8             mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)               # move 2.2 into arr[1] at memory address rbp - 0x18
  400551:   48 b8 66 66 66 66 66    movabs $0x400a666666666666,%rax       
  400558:   66 0a 40 
  40055b:   48 89 45 f0             mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)               # move 3.3 into arr[2] at memory address rbp - 0x10
  40055f:   48 b8 9a 99 99 99 99    movabs $0x401199999999999a,%rax       
  400566:   99 11 40 
  400569:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)                # move 4.4 into arr[3] at memory address rbp - 0x8
  40056d:   c7 45 dc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x24(%rbp)               # declaring i at memory address rbp-0x24 (notice this is at location arr[4] (kind of))
  400574:   eb 28                   jmp    40059e <main+0x71>
  400576:   8b 45 dc                mov    -0x24(%rbp),%eax
  400579:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `arr[4]` since `i` value goes till 4 because of `i<=4`. But you have only `arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3]` in the array. You have change the condition in the `for` loop to `i<4`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    double arr[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {     // Since you have only 4 values in the array
        printf("%d\n", i);
        arr[i] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted but I'd guess probably a lack of explanation

Comment: @gowrath, I have added some explanation, Thans for the suggestion.